# Is there a difference from one GND pin to another?

Tags: gpio

There are 4 ground pins on the GPIO are they all the same? Are the extra pins just there for convenience? I have an expansion breadboard does it matter which gnd slot I plug into?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference in the ground pins. As you surmise they are provided for convenience - some will be easier to connect to than others based on location, cable used etc. So no it does not matter which one you connect to your breadboard.